# How to remove scrollbar in a given app on Mac OS?

Tags: macos

Is there a way to remove scrollbars in a given app on Mac OS?

For example I'd like to do that in Finder. Most of the time I end up having trouble entering a folder because it is under the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to remove them. If you're referring to the fact that Lion and Mountain Lion have scroll bars that appear only briefly, you could make them appear the old way (Snow Leopard and previous), always visible.

There's an option in the General preference pane to always show the scroll bars.